# MysqlDataTruncation : Java evaluates SQL Date object as an expression

Tags: java, mysql, date

I need to insert Date to my database, so I convert date received from user to SQL Date and then try to insert date to database. But in process SQL date object is evaluate to integer and thus insertion fails .

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String enrollNo = request.getParameter("enroll_no");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String age = request.getParameter("age");

    java.util.Date date = null;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("dob"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date SqlDate = new Date(date.getTime());

    process(enrollNo, name, age, SqlDate);
    response.sendRedirect("listing.jsp");
}

void process(String enrollNo, String name, String age, Date date) {
    DatabaseOperations db = new DatabaseOperations("java", "root", "", "jsp");
    db.insert(enrollNo, name, age, date);
}
```

Insert method of DatabaseOperations class

```
public int insert(Object...objects) {
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    String query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (";

    for(int i=0; i<objects.length-1; i++)
        query += "'" + objects[i] + "',";

    query += objects[objects.length-1] + ")";

    try {
        rowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        printSQLExceptions(e);
    } 
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

While inserting date 11/02/2000 following error shows up

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '1987' for column 'Dob' at row 1
```

Comment: And this is just *one* reason why you should use parameterized SQL instead of embedding the values directly into the SQL itself. Please look at `PreparedStatement` and use it.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet But I need to develop a generalized method. So can be used by different classes.

Comment: I don't see how that prevents using parameterized SQL. I assume you don't *want* conversion problems and SQL injection vulnerabilities?